# How to filter foreign key related by user?

Tags: python, django

How do i filter this ?

```
class Base(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    base_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Sub_base(models.Model):
    base = models.ForeignKey(Base)
    sub_base_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now i just want to filter Sub_base based on current logged in user , how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated(): 
   subbases = Sub_base.objects.filter(base__user=request.user)
```

---

if `request.user.is_authenticated()`, then this user is logged in, otherwise the user is [Anonymous User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users)